# C# update query

Tags: c#, database

I am finding error of No value given for one or required parameter C# update query where ever i try to update my c# access data base here is the code...
hope somebody will be of my assistant..

```
private void updatebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       con.Open();
       OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
       cmd.Connection = con;
            string query = "update Emplyeedata set [ID]='" + midbox.Text + "',[Name]='" + mnamebox.Text + "',[Deisgnation]='" + mdesbox.Text + "',[Leave]='" + mleavebox.Text + "'Where [Name]='"+mnamebox.Text+"'";
       cmd.CommandText = query;

       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       con.Close();
       cb();
       MessageBox.Show("Updated", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
   }
   catch
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
   }                          
}
```

Comment: Please do not use string concatenation when you build a SQL query. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175528(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: Can you post the actual error you are getting please or we can't help.

Comment: Are you sure "Deisgnation" is spelled correctly? Access will throw "parameter" errors on unknown (misspelled) column names.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the actual (sql) execution line and check to see what the values of the variables are and what the actual SQL statement is. You could probably copy/paste that into the Access DB and see if it runs.  I find it a little weird that you are using `name` as the where qualifier instead of `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a bit more improvement you can try like this, and if you can post the full error information.

```
    private void updatebutton_Click()
    {
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Define your Connection String here"))
        {
            string query = @"UPDATE Emplyeedata
                        SET [id] = @ID
                           ,[Name] = @Name
                           ,[Deisgnation] = @Deisgnation
                           ,[Leave] = @Leave
                        WHERE [Name] = @Name";

            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con) { CommandType = CommandType.Text })
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", midbox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", mnamebox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Deisgnation", mdesbox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Leave", mleavebox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", mnamebox.Text);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

(this is a really unstructured way and please follow the **SOLID** Principle/s)

Comment: new OleDbConnection("ConnectionString") ,, youse your ConnectionString variable insted of ConnectionString text that i used as sample